# ping incorrectly pinging 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ping, gentoo

I've got an odd DNS issue. I'm running a dual ipv4/ipv6 environment on Gentoo Linux.

Pinging some sites results in ping pinging 127.0.0.1. e.g.

```
#> ping authserver.mojang.com
PING authserver.mojang.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
--- authserver.mojang.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.043/0.048/0.058/0.010 ms
```

Dig, however correctly returns the following:

```
# dig authserver.mojang.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-P2 <<>> authserver.mojang.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15800
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;authserver.mojang.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
authserver.mojang.com.  5       IN      A       54.235.119.47

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:4860:4860::8888#53(2001:4860:4860::8888)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 09 15:34:40 GMT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

I'm confused! My web browser returns the correct website, and the same computer booted into Windows also works correctly.

I've not altered /etc/hosts (I've altered my actual computer name to post here):
    127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost

```
# IPv4 and IPv6 localhost aliases
127.0.0.1       my.computer.com my localhost
::1             my.computer.com my localhost
```

My resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from eth0
options inet6
# Google
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

domain my.domain.com
```

**EDIT:**
My /etc/nsswitch.conf (untouched):

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf:
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo/src/patchsets/glibc/extra/etc/nsswitch.conf,v 1.1 2006/09/29     23:52:23 vapier Exp $

passwd:      compat
shadow:      compat
group:       compat

# passwd:    db files nis
# shadow:    db files nis
# group:     db files nis

hosts:       files dns
networks:    files dns

services:    db files
protocols:   db files
rpc:         db files
ethers:      db files
netmasks:    files
netgroup:    files
bootparams:  files

automount:   files
aliases:     files
```

As suggested, I ran strace on ping: [strace log](http://pastebin.com/GkaBsGg6)

It's not connecting to ncsd:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Then it tries to connect to Google's DNS:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:4860:4860::8888", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "\16\273\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\nauthserver\6mojang\3c"..., 39, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 39
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [55])                = 0
recvfrom(4, "\16\273\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\nauthserver\6mojang\3c"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:4860:4860::8888", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 55
close(4)                                = 0
```

Still not working!

As suggested, using -e read the last dns lookup is the following:

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:4860:4860::8888", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "M\354\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\nauthserver\6mojang\3c"..., 39, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 39
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [55])                = 0
recvfrom(4, "M\354\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\nauthserver\6mojang\3c"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:4860:4860::8888", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 55
 | 00000  4d ec 81 80 00 01 00 01  00 00 00 00 0a 61 75 74  M....... .....aut^? |
 | 00010  68 73 65 72 76 65 72 06  6d 6f 6a 61 6e 67 03 63  hserver. mojang.c^? |
 | 00020  6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01 c0  0c 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  om...... ........^? |
 | 00030  05 00 04 17 15 2d ec                              .....-.          ^? |
close(4)                                = 0
```

I'm afraid I don't know enough about DNS protocol to decode it. Full trace here: [Full strace](http://pastebin.com/HryXU0ai)

Comment: what about /etc/hosts? Dig directly queries nameservers, while you may have some overrides in /etc/hosts or are querying something else.

Comment: Did you play with `/etc/hosts`? What's in your `/etc/resolv.conf`? Did you use a private DNS?

Comment: Added files as requested. I haven't changed `/hosts`, and I use Google's public DNS.

Comment: What does your /etc/nsswitch.conf look like?

Comment: Try switching the order in nsswitch.conf from `files dns` to `dns files`. Also if you are running nscd have it flush the cache.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid that didn't work. I'm not using nscd - it's not running, though it is installed.

Comment: wow, I'm stumped. All I can suggest at this point is using this option. ` -e read=set Perform a full hexadecimal and ASCII dump of all the data  read  from  file  descriptors
                   listed in the specified set.  For example, to see all input activity on file descriptors
                   3 and 5 use -e read=3,5.  Note that this is independent from the normal tracing  of  the
                   read(2) system call which is controlled by the option -e trace=read.`

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms you describe (dig gives correct answer, gethostbyname does not ) means that somewhere in the system there is a cached incorrect answer.

Running

```
strace ping authserver.mojang.com
```

should help give you some idea of where that data might be cached. nscd is usually the culprit in this case. Look for connect calls, this is to a dns server.

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("134.79.110.9")}, 28) = 0
```

This one is to the nscd socket.

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = 0
```

You'll see send message with the dns name you're attempting to contact and one will respond with the localhost ip address. This is an example of a successful dns lookup.

```
sendto(4, "@\330\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\3www\4slac\10stanford\3e"..., 39, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 39

recvfrom(4, "@\330\205\200\0\1\0\2\0\4\0\7\3www\4slac\10stanford\3e"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("134.79.110.9")}, [16]) = 309
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Results have been added to the question. It does appear that a correct query is being performed.